# Where can I find html and css of Google search results?

Tags: html, css, styles

On my web site I would like to display results in a form which is very similar to the Google search results so that users can see what they are familiar with. Does anybody know where I can find the html and css that generates the output in the same style as the Google search result has? Looking at page source of the Google search results does not help.

Comment: Why does it not help? That's what you are looking for.

Comment: You want to copy it!? Seriously, just design your own.

Comment: @knittl, because it does not look as a html code. I cannot interpret it.

Comment: @Nathan MacInnes, why not to copy? Does Google has a copyright on this particular style?

Comment: Potentially yes. And they definitely hold copyright over their source code. Plus, there's no innovation in copying. How can the web move forward if everyone copies each other?

Comment: @Nathan MacInnes, for me it is hard to accept a copyright if a company chooses a shrift and color for title, text and link and then copyright it. In my opinion it should be impossible to copyright a combination of shrift and color. To me it is like to copyright a sphere so that other cannot use this shape. Sphere belongs to everybody. Moreover, I do not care much about innovations because I care about survival. And finally, I think it is better to focus on creating something new if there is a real need for that. Why to change something that already works fine?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know the html layout, get chrome and use inspect element, click on each element to see what CSS rules it is following. But copying google's css is very simple, blue links, black text, simple

Comment: Right click the page, go to the bottom of the thing that appears by your cursor and click `Inspect Element`

Comment: In all (IE, FF (needs firebug), Chrome) just hit F12 and check downloaded files.

Answer (score 4):

You've got the `<style id="gstyle"></style>` tag in `<head>` of each Google results page which include the style :

```
body{
   color:#000;
   margin:0;
   overflow-y:scroll
}
body,#leftnav,#tbdi,#hidden_modes,#hmp{
   background:#fff
}
...
```

There are about 54000 chars in this div, we can assume all you need is here.